# Resizing BasicArrowButton

Tags: java, swing, layout, resize

I'm trying to get a BasicArrowButton component to resize and can't get it to work for the life of me. The following code is a much simpler version of the problem, but still demonstrates what I'm trying to do. The button is in a JPanel with the panel's layout set to FlowLayout. It needs to resize while still remaining in the panel with the same layout. Thanks in advance, and sorry for bad formatting:

Main class:

```
package PackageMain;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Main {

public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");
public static PanelOne p1;
public static PanelTwo p2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
                p1 = new PanelOne();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Second Class:

```
package PackageMain;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicArrowButton;

public class PanelOne{

public PanelOne(){
    FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
    BasicArrowButton b1 = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.WEST);
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.add(b1);
    p1.setLayout(fl);
    b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100)); //DOESN'T WORK!
    Main.frame.add(p1);

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the class BasicArrowButton overrides the method getPreferredSize(). So you either need to use layout, which does not honor this method, or provide your own implementation for this method.

First proposal:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicArrowButton;

public class BasicArrowButtonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test arrow button");
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
                p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                p.add(new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.WEST));
                frm.add(p);
                frm.pack();
                frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frm.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Second proposal:

```
package org.swingsamples.label;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicArrowButton;

public class BasicArrowButtonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test arrow button");
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
                BasicArrowButton btn = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.WEST) {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(100, 100);
                    }
                };
                p.add(btn);
                frm.add(p);
                frm.pack();
                frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frm.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```